# Alter Sub to use IsText to IsText Or IsNumber excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

This works fine but I want it to work on text or numbers

```
Sub Cleanup()
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.offset(1,0)
  .Value = Evaluate("IF(ISTEXT(" & .Address & "), _
            TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" & .Address & ",CHAR(160),"""")), _
               REPT(" & .Address & ",1))")
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried (not working)

```
.Value = Evaluate("IF(oR(ISTEXT(" & .Address & "), _
          TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" & .Address & ",CHAR(160),"""")), _
          REPT(" & .Address & ",1), _
          IsNummeric((" & .Address & "),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(" & .Address & ",CHAR(160),"""")), _
          REPT(" & .Address & ",1)))")
```

But (after about an hour of trying) it just turns everything to `#value!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell containing a non-breaking space will never be considered a number no matter how many digits or decimal places it contains. Better to just replace all formulas with their returned values and remove all non-breaking spaces.

```
Sub Cleanup()

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.offset(1,0)
        .Value = .value
        .replace what:=chr(160), replacement:=vbnullstring, lookat:=xlpart
    End With

End Sub
```

Additional cleanup could be performed by removing lingering worksheet errors like `#N/A` or `#VALUE!` with the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx). This is also a way to look for numbers in formulas or typed values throughout the worksheet but as stated, if a cell contains a non-breaking space it will never be considered a number.

fwiw, your [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) may be leaving zero-length strings, not truly blank cells like the above procedure.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped for the code and the explanation, it was helpful